# G27Q vs Ei322QUR S vs XV272U

Tags: gaming, monitors

I'm about to get monitors for my PC and right now I'm between three: the [Gigabyte G27Q](https://www.gigabyte.com/Monitor/G27Q#kf), the [Acer EI322QUR Sbmiipphx](https://www.microcenter.com/product/663366/acer-ei322qur-sbmiipphx-315-2k-wqhd-(2560-x-1440)-165hz-curved-screen-gaming-monitor-platinum-collection), and the [Acer Nitro XV272U](https://www.microcenter.com/product/626571/acer-nitro-xv272u-27-2k-wqhd-(2560-x-1440)-170hz-gaming-monitor). As of right now, I'm thinking one of the Acer monitors because of their better refresh rate, but if there is something about the G27Q that makes it worth it then I would gladly take it. However, I can't decide between the two Acers. The EI322QUR is bigger and curved, but it has a slightly worse refresh rate and is VA panel type vs. IPS. Does the panel type matter that much? They are all pretty much the same price, so I can't justify a purchase based off of cost. My primary use case will be gaming. Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi prorustlover! I'm guessing you're mostly playing Rust or other competitive games, and not sightseeing games? What's your budget like?